# How to upgrade pyrogram to the latest version in linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, upgrade, pyrogram

I can't to upgrade pyrogram to latest version in Linux.

I'm using `pip3 install --upgrade pyrogram` and it looks like my program is not seeing a newer version of pyrogram.

But using the same command in Windows I was able to upgrade pyrogram to 2... version easily.

I'm using Python 3.6.9.

Information I'm getting:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pyrogram in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages

Requirement already up-to-date: pyaes==1.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyrogram)

Requirement already up-to-date: pysocks==1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyrogram)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer Pyrogram versions do not support Python 3.6 or older. You'll have to use a newer Python Version.